# How to get the content of an html method?

Tags: c#, stream

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2 and playing around with iCal Events.

I Generated my own `.ics` file and with Thunderbird I subscribe to that Calendar. Every time I change an Event in Thunderbird, it's fires a `PUT` and a `PROPFIND` methods.

In the `PUT` it sends the calendar file modified.

> **How** can I get that in an Action?

[image]

my current action is:

```
[HttpPut]
public void Index(string id) 
{

}
```

and it is fired normally, but how do I get the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dumb me

**:o(**

it's easy as:

```
Stream content = Request.InputStream;
```

so:

```
[HttpPut]
public void Index(string id) 
{
    Stream content = Request.InputStream;

    // Process content
}
```